# Is there a way to reference a column that's ambiguous?

Tags: redshift

This isn't an actual problem I'm having, just curiosity after a discussion with a colleague.

Given:

```
SELECT 1 as foo, 2 as foo;
```

How can you select values from one column:

```
SELECT foo
FROM (SELECT 1 as foo, 2 as foo);
```

Without:

> [42702] ERROR: column reference "foo" is ambiguous

The best I can come up with is a CTE where you would strictly need to know both every column and their order:

```
WITH remapped(foo, bar) AS (
  SELECT 1 as foo, 2 as foo
)
SELECT *
FROM remapped;
```

Or possibly doing pivots.

Answer (score 1):

The following query

```
WITH remapped(foo, bar) AS (
  SELECT 1 as foo, 2 as foo
)
SELECT *
FROM remapped;
```

Is the same as

```
SELECT foo,bar
FROM ( SELECT 1 as foo, 2 as bar ) subqry;
```

As per the question

> Is there a way to reference a column that's ambiguous?

Use alias.

When two columns have the same column name the SQL Machine is confused as to which column out of the two tables you are referring to, to select from. In this case you can use alias.

A 'real life scenario'

```
create table foo (id int ,name varchar(5));
create table bar (id_f int ,name varchar(5));


select name
from foo f
join bar b on f.id=b.id_f
```

Error

> Column 'name' in field list is ambiguous

Using alias

```
select f.name
from foo f
join bar b on f.id=b.id_f
```

or

```
select f.name as fname
from foo f
join bar b on f.id=b.id_f
```